# Firewall settings on Azure Blob using Microsoft Teams - Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, microsoft-teams

We are building a chat-bot using Bot Framework and Microsoft Teams.
To enrich the conversation between the Bot and user, we want to use Images with Azure Storage Blobs.
These images are accessible within the network of the enterprise (firewall on Azure Storage account to restrict access).

[image]

The image is correctly rendered on web test console, but not on Teams.
After my investigation, I found that Teams changes the URL of the Image to:

https://urlp.asm.skype.com/v1/url/content?url=[original_url]

My understanding is to allow IP ranges of the server "urlp.asm.skype.com" but I cannot find the exact answer in the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges#skype-for-business-online-and-microsoft-teams

Could you provide a workaround or the exacte IP range of urlp.asm.skype.com ?

What i have tested:
- Allow access from all network, Images are loaded.
- Allowed network 52.112.0.0/14 according to dns result, images are not loaded. (I think it is not sufficient)

Thanks

Comment: Image URLs must be publicly accessible. We don’t officially support allowing access to a range of IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks. The ip range will be applied on Azure Storage. For internal use bot, if we store images to a publicly accessible location, Security team will surely block the project. If i allow the access from Teams' image cache server (urlp.asm.skype.com), it should be fine. but i can't find a list of possible IPs of that server.